# Get the space used by a table in Apache Derby

Tags: database, derby

Is it possible to get how much space is used by a table in Apache Derby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement returns the size for each table:

```
select
    tableName,
    (select sum(numallocatedpages * pagesize) from new org.apache.derby.diag.SpaceTable('APP', t.tablename) x) as size
from SYS.SYSTABLES t
order by size desc
```

Comment: This query gives null sizes. Apache derby version 10.11.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Following query show space usage for both tables as well as indexes.

```
SELECT 
    ((T2.PAGESIZE * T2.NUMALLOCATEDPAGES) / 1024 / 1024) AS "SIZE IN MB",  
    T2.*
    FROM 
    SYS.SYSTABLES systabs,
        TABLE (SYSCS_DIAG.SPACE_TABLE(systabs.tablename)) AS T2
WHERE systabs.tabletype = 'T'
ORDER by ISINDEX, 1 DESC;
```

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsyscsdiagtables.html

Answer (score 0):

To remove null sizes that appear for non-APP schema tables try this modified query based on Fidels.

```
select
tableName,
(select sum(numallocatedpages * pagesize) from new 
 org.apache.derby.diag.SpaceTable('APP', t.tablename) x) as size
from SYS.SYSTABLES t
where t.SCHEMAID = (select schemaid from sys.sysschemas where schemaname = 
'APP') 
order by size desc
```